# cors blocking keycloak auth endpoint in express server middleware

Tags: express, keycloak, sveltekit, keycloak-connect, keycloak-js

I'm getting a cors error when trying to calling a `keycloak.protected` endpoint.
I'm calling it from a svelte front-end app. The middleware is running on an express server.

Here's the full project code:

front-end: https://github.com/roberttootill98/keycloak-client

server: https://github.com/roberttootill98/keycloak-server

The request works fine when using the bearer token obtained by the front end in postman.

Here's the full error:
[Full cors error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7krWY.png)

Here's the keycloak access settings:
[Keycloak access settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlpbZ.png)

Comment: Hi, using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you